# "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data." when navigating to localhost port bound to docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am running docker desktop for windows version 3.0.0 and am attempting to setup a basic hello world example using docker and docker-compose.  when I run `docker-compose up` the containers build fine and log the appropriate `Server running at...` messages.

However when I navigate to `localhost:3000` I would expect to see 'Hello World' and am instead seeing a browser error reading "This page isn’t working  localhost didn’t send any data."

when I run the server.js file directly in node, I get "hello world" at `localhost:3000` as expected.

Ideally I would be able to access all of my docker containers on local host ports 3000-3003.  relevant files are below.

Each of my dockerfiles contain the following

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Below is the server.js file:

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

My docker-compose file is below:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  analyze:
    build: services/analyze/
    volumes:
      - ./services/analyze:/analyze
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  extract:
    build: services/extract/
    volumes:
      - ./services/extract:/extract
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
  search:
    build: services/search/
    volumes:
      - ./services/search:/search
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
  reply:
    build: services/reply/
    volumes:
      - ./services/reply:/reply
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
```

Comment: You need to change `hostname = '0.0.0.0'` or omit that parameter entirely.  If you `listen(port, '127.0.0.1')` the service won't be accessible from outside its container.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This resolved the issue.